# Python script not deleting from mysql

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

my python script won't delete a certain mysql table entry which can not be older than 6 Minutes.
Tagid is the id of a rfid tag. It seems to do nothing regarding the delete....gives back no error, gives back the time of the entry in question, so the rest of my script tells me that the entry has been deleted (succefully deleted) which is wrong once i check the db manually.... Any help is greatly appreciated

python mysql script

```
def deleteLastReading(tagId):
    '''Deletes last reading inserted max 5(+1) minutes ago'''
    checkTime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=6)
    db = connect()
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM readings WHERE tagId=%s AND time>%s ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1",(tagId,checkTime.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    db.close()
```

python delete

```
        onScreen("Success")
        onScreen(lastAction)
        onScreen(lastTime)
        logging.info(" - Deleting action %s (cas: %s)",lastAction, lastTime)
        mysql.deleteLastReading(cardId)
        onScreen("Successfully deleted")
        display.lcdWriteSecondLine("Deleted!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do unnecessary fetching operation. And I will try to assume that your connection is not running in autocommit mode. That means you have to commit your changes manually.

```
def deleteLastReading(tagId):
    '''Deletes last reading inserted max 5(+1) minutes ago'''
    checkTime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=6)
    db = connect()
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM readings WHERE tagId=%s AND time>%s ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1",(tagId,checkTime.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")))
    cur.execute("COMMIT")
    db.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, now it gets deleted properly.